# Postgres duplicate key value violates unique constraint for autogenerated column

Tags: postgresql

Inserting a row is throwing unique constraint violation on a auto-generated column when running with a bash script

```
psql -Atx "$DB_CONNECTION_STRING" -c "INSERT INTO my_table(mt_version) VALUES ('0.1.11')"
```

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_version_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (puck_firmware_version_id)=(66) already exists.
```

When I run with dbeaver, it adds the new row and generates the id with no issue `my_table(mt_version) values ('0.1.2')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync?r=SearchResults&s=1|615.8581

Answer (score 2):

Someone must have inserted a row with an explicit value for `id`, overriding the generated default value. That row caused a collision with the automatically generated value from your `INSERT` statement.

This had nothing to do with the client in use, and it is a coincidence that you could trigger the error from `psql`, but not from DBeaver.

The best way to prevent such a situation is to define generated primary keys with `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`, so that it becomes more difficult to override the generated value.

As a solution for your present problem, either delete the conflicting manually inserted rows or reset the sequence to a value higher than any existing `id` in the table.